# Prediction Model for the number of defects

Tags: r, glmm

I work at a software company, and we are trying to build a statistical model to predict the defect density (the number of defects that exist in a certain software release that is delivered to a customer divided by the number of person months that it took to develop the software release).

We have 15 independent variables. The dependent variable seems to follow a Poisson distribution, but it is continuous. A large part of the data is in the neighborhood of 0. We have 284 observations.

I tried to run a regression tree. With `rpart` I got only a root. With `ctree` I arrived at a more detailed tree. Do you know what the reason for this might be? How can I compare them?

I also tried GLM with quasi-Poisson. I am not sure that this appropriate because the dependent variable is continuous. Do you think that this model is appropriate for use? If so, how can I estimate it (there is no AIC in the R output)?
Other suggestions are also welcome.
Thanks!

Comment: So your dependent variable (defect density) is right skew, right? That is, it has a long right tail? Have you tried taking logs? Or, if there are some true 0's, taking square roots?

Comment: Or if there are a lot of true zeros (not just numbers close to zero), maybe a zero-inflated model?

Comment: @PeterFlom Yes. it is right skew. and if I take square root what should I do next? Thanks

Comment: @NickStauner I want to try the zero inflated as well. is it appropriate for continuous data? Thanks

Comment: Try OLS regression; another possibility is quantile regression, particularly if you are interested in what predicts very high (or low) defect rates.

Comment: Yes, zero-inflated gamma regression may be worth trying if you have a lot of true zeroes and an otherwise continuous distribution that resembles a Poisson distribution.

Comment: @PeterFlom one of my independent variable is the defect density of the previous software release (for the same customer). Should I take the square root of that as well and then perform linear regression?

Comment: If you have multiple measurements for each piece of software you need to account for that, possibly with a multi-level model